# VBA problem with String concatenation

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

I want to create a query like this :

```
SQL = SQL + "Libelle = \"" + Me.Libelle + "\" AND "
```

because if I have a problem with my data if I write like this :

```
SQL = SQL + "Libelle = '" + Me.Libelle + "' AND "
```

but there is a problem with the \" 
I'm used to use it in Java (I'm not a VBA developper :s)
How to resolve it ? 
thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a concatenation with the Chr(34) :)

```
SQL = SQL + "Libelle = " + Chr(34) + Me.Libelle + Chr(34) + " AND "
```

Comment: You should not use + to concatenate strings.

Comment: You should use the + concatenation operator if you want to propagate Nulls and the & if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA use & to concatenate strings, + will lead to unexpected results. Jet SQL uses two single quotes to escape a single quote. It is normal to use Replace to get this.

```
 SQL = SQL & "Libelle = '" & Replace(Me.Libelle,"'","''") & "' AND "
```

Comment: In VBA and Jet/ACE SQL the & concatenation operator ignores Null (Null & "" = "") while the + concatenation operator propagates Nulls (Null + "" = Null). Null concatenation is quite useful in expressions like Mid(("12 + LastName) & (", " + FirstName), 3), but you have to be careful not to try to use it with numeric fields (or strings that can be implicitly coerced to numeric values), since while "12" + Null will propagate the Null, "12" + "8" MAY add the numeric values of the two strings (it depends on the context).

Answer (score 0):

In VB you get a literal quote with two quotes. "abc""def" yields abc"def.

What you want is:

```
SQL = SQL & "Libelle = """ & Me.Libelle & """ AND "
```

Comment: Do not use plus (+) to concatenate strings in VBA unless you understand what happens if one of the strings is null.

Comment: The ANSI standard for SQL specifies single quotes (').

Comment: Well, use the + concatenation operator if you want to propagate Nulls. I use it frequently, but you have to be careful (as my extensive comment above explains).

Comment: Why should I as an Access developer care particularly if the ANSI standard for SQL uses single quotes? Access doesn't, so isn't that more relevant than an outside standard that is not implemented in Access?